# How to select two columns as one?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search two fields as one from a MySQL database using PHP.

**e.g.**

```
mysql_query("
  SELECT (first_name,last_name) As name
  FROM people
  WHERE (name LIKE '%" . $term . "%')
");
```

I thought that this was the code to use, but to no avail. It has been a while since I've done this and I can't remember exactly how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You're looking for the [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) As name FROM people WHERE (CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE '%" . $term . "%')");
```

or even...

```
mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) As name FROM people WHERE (CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%" . $term . "%')");
```

I couldn't explain you the reasons behind this (...but maybe someone can leave a comment?), but you can't use the `name` alias to search for both fields, you have to explicitly `CONCAT` again.

Comment: @Vache, You cannot use an alias in a where clause, because the where clause may execute before the alias is resolved. If you want to use the alias, put it in a `having` clause. This may effect the runtime of the query however because you are forcing SQL to resolve the alias before the filter is applied.

Comment: So it works if I don't user the `WHERE (name LIKE '%". $term ."'")`, but when using the like it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to use the alias in a filter, rewrite the query to: `SELECT CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS name FROM people HAVING name LIKE 'Vache IAm'`

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work if i do it like:

    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%" . $term . "%'");

Comment: @Bobby, `select *` is an SQL anti-pattern. It's a bad idea for lots of reasons. Always name your columns explicitly.

Comment: What if we want to put an unknown number of columns to one? For example if a subquery can output multiple rows we could put the into one column instead of recieving an error?

Answer (score 4):

[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

or

[`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: I use both of these regularly - the concat returns null if *any* value is null - this can be useful occasionally `concat(distance, 'km')` - but more often than not concat_ws is better, for example: `concat_ws(' ', first, middle, last)`